# I'm sure someone has seen this: Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached. with LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity

The scenario I am using LINQ is as follows:
I have a method that queries a table and returns one record using the following code

```
private L2SQLData.PatientFile getpatfile(long id)
{
   var db = new HMSDataContext();
   var patfile = 
   (from f in db.PatientFiles.Where(f=> f.Id == id) select   f).FirstOrDefault() ;

   return patfile;
}
```

Then another code calls the method above and takes object/record that was returned. Then deletes it from the same table as follows:

```
L2SQLData.PatientFile patfile = getpatfile(long.Parse(id));

var db = new HMSDataContext();
db.PatientFiles.DeleteOnSubmit(patfile);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

On running it, VS2010 screams with the error: Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached. What am I doing wrong? Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `db.PatientFiles.Attach(patfile)` or try using only one globaly ***HMSDataContext***

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I used the attach method but I got an error:'An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.' I am also trying to avoid using global datacontext because of the ptoential to slow down the web application due to open connections that stay for long periods even when not in use.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution! I queried the data context object to retrieve the object with same id as the one returned then deleted from same data context.

```
var delpatfile = db.PatientFiles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == patfile.Id);
                 db.PatientFiles.DeleteOnSubmit(delpatfile);
                 db.SubmitChanges();
```

Since it was coming from same data context, it was already attached. I guess it might not be the only way to go about this so if anyone still has answers, feel free to post.

Thanks.