# How can I delete a record using Linq to SQL without getting the error: Cannot delete an entity that is not linked?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, sql-delete

Im building an app in C# using LINQ to SQL. Currently you can insert data into the database, and I want to add a delete function as well.

This is the code I use to do it.

Top of the page:

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    Dealer hetDealer = new Dealer();
```

This code is used to get the data from a listbox.

```
private void Lb_dealer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        hetDealer = (Dealer)lb_dealer.SelectedItem;
    }
```

This code is used to delete the data

```
private void Btn_dealer_verwijder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Dealers.DeleteOnSubmit(hetDealer);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

The Dealer table looks like this:

```
-------------------------
| did (PK) | dealername |
-------------------------
```

Sadly the record I try to delete doesnt get deleted. Instead I get this message as soon as I click on delete (translated):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot delete an entity that is not linked.
```

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Is hetDealer null?

Comment: hetDealer contains data from a listbox, I just checked the output

Comment: listbox gets data from the database

Comment: So it contains data at : db.Dealers.DeleteOnSubmit(hetDealer)?  If it has data then the DeleteOnSubmit() method is giving the error.  I usually from VS menu degug : Break All.  Then menu Debug : Windows : Call Stack to help determine how the code got to the exception.

Comment: So there is not an obvious error in the code I put in the question? Do you have any tips on what I could try?

Comment: You did not post the DeleteOnSubmit method.  How can I tell from code if an object is null?

Comment: I'm guessing the error message is _Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached._ If so that usually happens if you have multiple datacontexts. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204491/im-sure-someone-has-seen-this-cannot-remove-an-entity-that-has-not-been-attach help?